# cURL to array_map with utf8_encode in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using a cURL request to grab data from a website and adding them to properties within a loop later. However, I'm stuck on making the data adjustable enough where I can add them directly within the objects.

I have a cURL request that I'm calling that grabbing all the content that I need as below:

```
public function request()
{
    $resource = curl_init();
    curl_setopt(
        $resource,
        CURLOPT_URL,
        'lorem ipsum'
    );
    curl_setopt(
        $resource,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        ['API Auth']
    );
    curl_setopt(
        $resource,
        CURLOPT_REFERER,
        'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/'
    );
    curl_setopt(
        $resource,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
        'F'
    );
    curl_setopt(
        $resource,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,
        1
    );
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($resource), true);

    if (!curl_errno($resource)) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($resource);
        echo 'Took ', $info['total_time'], ' seconds to send a request to ', $info['url'], "\n";
    };

    return $response;
}
```

When I call the following execution `$offices_array = $this->request();` `print_r2($offices_array);`, this is the return that I receive:

```
Array
(
    [paginator] => Array
        (
            [total] => 131
            [per_page] => 500
            [current_page] => 1
            [last_page] => 1
            [prev_page] => 
            [next_page] => 
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Atlanta
                )
```

I'm using this function _csv_to_array:

```
private function _csv_to_array($filepath) {
    $data_array = array();
    if(is_readable($filepath)) {
        $fp = fopen($filepath, 'r');
        while(($data_item = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, "\t")) !== false) {
            $data_array[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $data_item);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    return $data_array;
}
```

to print out data as this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABU DHABI 
            [1] => FHI  
        )
```

How could I do something similar with the cURL request?

Comment: `utf8_encode` will not convert any of that data into `ABU DHABI` and `FHI`.

Comment: What is your desired output from the cURL response?

Comment: I understand, I just want it to be in the same Array format output such as [0] [1] / @BenM -I want it to be into the [0] [1] array format instead of the words.

Comment: Or actually, how I have it in the csv output such as `trim($office_array['0'])` for [0] => ABU DHABI .. could I just use `trim($office_array['id'])` for the output [id] => 1 from the cURL? @AbraCadaver